# Huawei E3372 Mode_Switch Issue

Tags: usb, raspberry-pi, modem

I am trying to switch mode of Modem so that i can access internet on Raspberry Pi.

On running lsusb:

```
lsusb
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 022: ID 0a05:7211 Unknown Manufacturer hub
Bus 001 Device 021: ID 12d1:14fe Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. Modem (Mass Storage Mode)
Bus 001 Device 018: ID 0a05:7211 Unknown Manufacturer hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMSC9512/9514 Fast Ethernet Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMC9514 Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The mode_switch.config looks as follow

```
 # Configuration for the usb_modeswitch package, a mode switching tool for
# USB devices providing multiple states or modes
#
# Evaluated by the wrapper script /usr/sbin/usb_modeswitch_dispatcher
#
# To enable an option, set it to "1", "yes" or "true" (case doesn't matter)
# Everything else counts as "disable"


# Disable automatic mode switching globally (e.g. to access the original
# install storage)

DisableSwitching=0

# Disable check for MBIM module presence and configuration globally (to aid
# special embedded environments)

DisableMBIMGlobal=0

# Enable logging (results in a extensive report file in /var/log, named
# "usb_modeswitch_<interface-name>" and probably others

EnableLogging=0


# Optional increase of "delay_use" for the usb-storage driver; there are hints
# that a recent kernel default change to 1 sec. may lead to problems, particu-
# larly with USB 3.0 ports. Set this to at least 3 (seconds) in that case.
# Does nothing if the current system value is same or higher

SetStorageDelay=4
DefaultVendor=0x12d1
DefaultProduct=0x14fe

TargetVendor=  0x12d1
TargetProduct= 0x1506

MessageContent="55534243123456780000000000000011062000000100000000000000000000"
```

After this i run 
    sudo usb_modeswitch -s 15 -I -H -c /etc/usb_modeswitch.conf

```
Look for target devices ...
 No devices in target mode or class found
Look for default devices ...
   product ID matched
 Found devices in default mode (1)
Access device 021 on bus 001
Get the current device configuration ...
Current configuration number is 1
Use interface number 0
 with class 8
Use endpoints 0x01 (out) and 0x81 (in)

USB description data (for identification)
-------------------------
Manufacturer: HUAWEI_MOBILE
     Product: HUAWEI_MOBILE
  Serial No.: 0123456789ABCDEF
-------------------------
Warning: MessageContent/StandardEject ignored; can't combine with special mode
Send old Huawei control message ...
```

The output of lsusb remains same.

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 022: ID 0a05:7211 Unknown Manufacturer hub
Bus 001 Device 021: ID 12d1:14fe Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. Modem (Mass Storage Mode)
Bus 001 Device 018: ID 0a05:7211 Unknown Manufacturer hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMSC9512/9514 Fast Ethernet Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMC9514 Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I am using the modem on external powered usb hub.
Please help

Answer (score 0):

1. Open `mode_switch.config` and turn on the following flag:

   ```
   DisableSwitching=0
   ```
2. Run this command:

   ```
   sudo usb_modeswitch -v 12d1 -p 14fe -V 12d1 -P 1506 -M '55534243123456780000000000000011060000000000000000000000000000'
   ```

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.